# append '01-' to strong parameter on rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a form that uses [jQuery datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/) for picking just the month and year.

```
$(".date-input").datepicker({
                  format: 'mm-yyyy', 
                  startView: "months", 
                  minViewMode: "months" 
                });
```

I have postgreSQL db on the backend with datetime column storing this date which apparently needs date in full format 'dd-mm-yyyy' to save it. While POSTing the form to my controller, this is what i came across:

`Experience.update(date_from: '02-2016')` updates the table with nil value for date_from column

So, the question is how can i append `'01-'` into this date_from param that i receive from POST request on the controller as Strong parameters.

Comment: I don't think you need to do anything with strong params, you can just modify the params values before saving in controller action.

Comment: if you just want month and year saved in the backend, I suggest having a different column as that will save you from lot of confusions. Also at the time of query you don't need to run the logic again to extract both of them.

Comment: makes sense to modify on the action for a single record.. but i'm dealing with has_many nested attributes.. so there'll be multiple `Experience` objects nested on a single POST request like  `"experiences_attributes"=> {"0"=>  {"id"=>"1", "date_from" => "02-2010"}, {"1"=>  {"id"=>"2", "date_from" => "02-2011"} }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [ISO8601 Date](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/iso8601.htm) format (2016-10-21).

```
$(".date-input").datepicker({
                  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd', 
                  startView: "months", 
                  minViewMode: "months" 
                });
```

You can parse it with `Date.iso8601(str)` or `DateTime.iso8601(str)`.

I would create a model level setter which handles this:

```
class Experience < ActiveRecord::Base # or ApplicationRecord
  def date_from=(val)
     super( val.is_a?(String) ? Date.iso8601(val) : val )
  end
end
```

This means you don't have to worry about the params on the controller level. Just whitelist it like any other scalar value and let your model do the work.

I would just store the values as a DATE type (as the first day of the month). Thats gives you the maximum flexibility when comes to DB querying and also a sane format when you pull records so that you don't have to parse a string again.

Comment: yes.. doing it on model makes sense.. i was trying it with `before_save` filter on model.. thanks for pointing out setter method

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with strong parameters.  When you get the data from the backend using strong params, you can access the information in the controller.  You can try something like this -

```
def create
    datestr = date_params[:datestr]
    date = Date.strptime("01-".concat(datestr), "%d-%m-%Y")
    Experience.update(date_from: date)
end

private

def date_params
    params.require(:dateinfo).permit(:datestr)
end
```